# Why does the Android NDK use different GCC versions for 32-bit and 64-bit ABIs?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Made GCC 4.8 the default for all 32-bit ABIs**. Deprecated GCC 4.6, and
> will remove it next release. To restore previous behavior, either add
> NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.6 to ndk-build, or add
> --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 when executing make-standalone-toolchain.sh on the command line. **GCC 4.9 remains the
> default for 64-bit ABIs**.

Specifically, is there any reason not to use GCC 4.9 for 32-bit ABIs as well? We need `std::regex` support which was only added in 4.9.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably mostly for pragmatic reasons. The default version for 32 bit is lagging behind a bit, since the old versions are more proven, and if there are no direct issues with them, they have probably preferred to stay with them.

For the 64 bit ABIs, in particular aarch64, the support in older GCC versions might not have been mature enough. Additionally, those ABIs haven't been supported at all before, so there's no risk of regressions since it's a completely new configuration.

If you need features from GCC 4.9, just add `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9`. There shouldn't be any issues in principle, but if there are I'm sure they'd love to hear reports about it if you run into anything.